# Call Recording is Available or Not in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0, call-recording

can any one Guide me `Call Recording` feature is available Or not in Android 10..
If anyone has a code for call recording that works on Android 10 so please share me!

Answer (score 1):

It was depreciated since android 10 but you can use third party apps to do that.
It might need root rights on some devices though.

Comment: Any Idea for Future Version Google will Resolve this Issue..In `Android 11' is Solved Or Not @Stay Strawberry

Comment: Officially google won't release such feature in next OS version